# mysql-slow.log displays 'information_schema' queries when 'log-queries-not-using-indexes' is enabled

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

I enabled `log-queries-not-using-indexes` in /etc/my.cnf

I can see now my queries without indexes but the issue is my log is full of queries like this:

> SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE
>   COLLATION_NAME = 'utf8_general_ci';
>
> SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE
>   COLLATION_NAME = 'utf8mb4_bin';

I know it's a bad idea to make changes on this database 'information_schema', so how to avoid to have theses queries in my logs?

Answer (score 0):

- In my opinion, `log_queries_not_using_indexes` is virtually useless.  It has some use briefly during development, but it is noise in production.
- `information_schema`, at least before 8.0, had no indexes and were not 'real' tables.
- Why are you reaching to `information_schema` so often?  See if you can cut back on the number of such calls.

Comment: `information_schema` is called by the system, not by my scripts. Maybe due to cPanel OS, not sure.